# R - Dataframe to JSON

Tags: json, r

I have a question regarding data.frames and jsonlite.

I have the following data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(lat = c(1,2),lng = c(2,3))
```

I want to parse this into the following format:

```
'{"locations": [
   {"latLng": {
        "lng": 2,
        "lat": 1
   }},{"latLng": {
        "lng": 3,
        "lat": 2
  }}]}
```

Using the jsonlite package, the following command

```
toJSON(df,pretty=T)
```

correctly sets the "lat" and "lng" variables. However, it misses the "latLng" identifier.

Is it possible to add this ("latLng"), without having to encapsulate every row of the dataframe in a list, which defines the identifier?

Thanks for your help.